# Editing an R command at the interactive prompt in windows

Tags: windows, r

Is there any way to make it easier to move around a long R command in the windows GUI? Help -> Console says left, right, home, and end are the only options available (contrast that with this: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#The-command_002dline-editor).  Is it possible to go back and forwards by word, or search for a string within the line?

Comment: maybe try [rstudio](http://rstudio.org) and if you don't like that, notepad++ with [npptor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npptor/)  :)

Comment: So I am aware of other ways to use R...I actually use the Vim-R plugin in vim for writing scripts. But there are plenty of times where using interactive R is the best way to test things out - hence the question.

Comment: ?? Can you provide an example of something that can be tested via the Windows R-gui but not in JGR, RStudio, or the Terminal command line?

Comment: You can use `Home` and `End` to go to the start and end of the line respectively

Answer (score 1):

No. The GUI assumes you will be able to use the horizontal scrollbar controls. (.... or that you will be using a real editor.)  There are such methods in the Rterm.exe version of R that are basically inherited from [the readline function](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html).